# Acessar função de um outro Component (Angular5)

Tags: angular

Suponha que no meu componentA eu tenho uma lista de produtos.
No meu componentB tenho um modal que cadastra meus produtos.
Ao cadastrar um produto, quero que o componentB chame uma função do componentA para atualizar a lista de produtos.. Como posso fazer isso?

Já tentei assim e não funciona: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38974896/call-child-component-method-from-parent-class-angular

att

Comment: eu sugiro que você centralize essa lista de produtos em um serviço, injetando o mesmo nos componentes.

Comment: Essa também me parece a melhor opção, porém.. Como vou manter essa lista no service se ela vêm de uma requisição http?

Comment: Consegui resolver utilizando o EventEmitter, confesso que não fiquei muito satisfeito..
No componentB, ao inserir um registro faço a call do service que retorna os produtos e atualizo a lista do componentA passando a lista atualizada via EventEmitter..
Acha muito ruim essa abordagem?

Comment: por que não criar um `Observable` de produtos? O serviço é o cara central que têm a lista dos produtos. Quem precisa referenciar os produtos dá um `subscribe`.

Comment: Tudo bem, dessa forma fica centralizado o método que retorna produtos..
Acontece que só utilizando esse conceito não resolve meu problema, porque estou utilizando esse modal (https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples), ou seja, o modal é um component, que na prática é outro escopo..
Após inserir um produto no modal, preciso que a lista do component pai seja atualizada.. Só com observable não tem como resolver esse problema.

Comment: Da uma olhada em behavior subject como nesse exemplo -> https://scotch.io/tutorials/3-ways-to-pass-async-data-to-angular-2-child-components

Answer (score 3):

Provavelmente o modal é injetado dinamicamente e não está sempre ali presente para trabalhar com eventos entre pai e filho direto.

Para o seu problema, eu sugiro trabalhar com Eventos Globais, esse tipo de evento, conhecido como broadcast, pode ser ouvido de qualquer local do aplicativo, e não só entre descendentes diretos.

Dessa forma, você se inscreveria nesse evento global (que chamo aqui de 'refreshProdutos') no seu componentA:

```
refreshEvento: any = null;

ngOnInit() {
    this.refreshEvento = EventEmitterService.get('refreshProdutos').subscribe(e => this.carregaProdutos());
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.refreshEvento !== null) this.refreshEvento.unsubscribe();
}
```

E no seu componentB, ao atualizar ou cadastrar um novo item, você dispararia esse evento:

```
salvarProduto() {
    // envia os dados para o servidor e no retorno dispara o evento global:
    EventEmitterService.get('refreshProdutos').emit(true);
}
```

Assim, todos, em qualquer parte da aplicação, que se inscreveram neste evento, vai receber a sinalização e cada um toma sua atitude, no caso, atualizar a lista.

Tem um artigo que ensina a criar esses eventos globais no Angular para ser usado como nos exemplos acima:
https://blog.wgbn.com.br/broadcast-de-eventos-no-angular-2-cb97a5ad6ff1